# Cannot modify iptables on CentOS

Tags: firewall, centos, iptables

My question: How to add a custom iptables rule to accept connection on a certain port?

I'm trying to open port 3500 on my server but failed.
I started by using this command: (From http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3500 -j ACCEPT
```

But then I run `iptables -L` I still do not see the new rules being listed: (My assumption it should include 3500 in the output)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:rtmp-port 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any 
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:snmp 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:snmptrap 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

**Edit**
So I try to insert ACCEPT rule to the INPUT chain and my iptables now look like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3500 
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

But it does not allow me to connect to 3500 from outside. (I can still telnet from inside). When I'm trying to telnet my_host 3500, I get this: `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

**Edit 2**: My `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "` output:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3500              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:973                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN

**Edit 3**: I followed lain advise, also have my service bind to 0.0.0.0:3500 instead of 127.0.0.1:3500 and it works.

Comment: did you run `/sbin/service iptables save` or `iptables save` ?
actually, wait, nevermind - you did. that is why all of those rules are under the INPUT chain. Just do what lain said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your rules is listed, `rtmp-port` is port 3500 according to IANA [port/service](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml) names. To get a listing of port numbers rather than their service names use the `-n` switch

```
iptables -L -n
```

You have also use the -A switch to add your rule to the INPUT chain. This has added after the packets have been sent to the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT chain, the last rule of which is a blanket REJECT so packets destined for port 3500 will be REJECTed before they get tested in the INPUT Chain.

You have a couple of possible solutions - use the `-I` switch to insert your rule to the `INPUT` chain or the `RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` chain

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3500 -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp --dport 3500 -j ACCEPT
```

You should probably clean up your rules too, you can use

```
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 3500 -j ACCEPT
```

(several times) to delete the existing rules for port 3500 before adding the new rules.

Comment: I followed your advise but still cannot connect. I modified my question to include some details.

Comment: Can you confirm that service is running? Try running "telnet localhost 3500" within the server verify?

Comment: telnet localhost 3500
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: telnet push.mycustomdomain.com 3500
Trying xxx.xx.xxx.xx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: This looks like there is nothing listening on your push.mycustomdomain.com:3500. With an open port and nothing listening I get `Connection Refused` with a closed port I get `No route to host`

Comment: Just updated my question with netstat -an. Look like my service was binding to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0. Would that be the cause?

Comment: Yes it's not listening on your external IP address.

Comment: Thanks man. I bound my service to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 and connection can be made now. Thanks a ton. You really enlightened me about *nix firewall.